# Closing application after pressing back button, not returning to previous activity

Tags: android

**problem:**

**Working scenario:**
I have a MainMenuActivity and when i start another activity and press Back Button it return to previous activity,but...

**Problem scenario:** When I start Activity B, from Activity A, and then press Home button and i after few seconds back to application, and then press Back button application is closed/minimalized. But i want after minimalized application can go back to Activity A.

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: Is it ALWAYS the same Activity you want to go back? And do you pass any data to it if you go back?

Comment: Technicly yes. it is always the same Activity, but not the same fragment in this activity.

Comment: Did you set back navigation parent to activity B?

Comment: You can finish Activity A before starting Activity B...So when you press the back button the application exits..

Comment: @DDsix u mean something like that :
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".activity.PromotionDetails" />

Comment: @KamilJeglikowski Okay i see. I hoped you can just overwrite the onBackPressed method, but i guess u cant get back to the right fragment then?

Comment: @NikosMitropoulos i dont want close Activity A. i Want could always can return from Activity B to Activity A.

Comment: @JoshuadV After minimalized application, when i press backbutton in Activity B my app was closed, and does not go back to Activity A

Comment: Try call NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this); in your onBackPressed() method

Comment: @NikosMitropoulos Yes i know, but you can overwrite the onBackPressed Method in your activity and go back to Activity A

Comment: @DDsix this is not working for me.

Comment: @JoshuadV how should  override onBackPressed method, can u give me any sample?

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question, do you mean how to override the onBackPressed, or what the overriden method should contain?

Comment: what it should contain :)

Comment: Well normally it would call finish(); so the current activity closes, and the focus goes to the previous. Your previous is the homescreen, so i guess thats why you have to override it. Due to your specific fragments, a simple Intent call of the previous activity dont solves the problem right?

Comment: It is not working correctly when i put "finish()" to onBackPressed... There is no another option wiothout creating new Intent?

Comment: Well i dont know, yet :/ Did you override your onPause or onStop in your Activity where you go to HomeScreen?

Comment: No, i not overrired this methods.

Comment: According to Tasks and Back Stack http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html it should exactly do what you want.

Comment: When the user leaves a task by pressing the Home button, the current activity is stopped and its task goes into the background. The system retains the state of every activity in the task. If the user later resumes the task by selecting the launcher icon that began the task, the task comes to the foreground and resumes the activity at the top of the stack.

Comment: So I guess anywhere in the Code you may have added an additional finish() so that Activity B forgets Activity A :(

Comment: Try to override your onPause() method in the activity which goes to Homescreen with the following:
onSaveInstanceState();

Comment: Ok i fixed this problem. My teammate added to Android Manifest  to each activities "android:launchmode:single" and this crashed app.

Comment: By the way, thanks a lot for yours help guys.